# Is it possible to to get the filepath of the file that uses an alias to import in Vite (Vue3)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vite

Good day!

I have a couple of questions. Is it possible to to get the filepath of the file that uses an
alias to import in Vite (Vue3) ?

### Set-up

I have this directory structure, for rhetorical purposes only:

```
src/ 
    module_a/ 
        some_script.js 
        another_script.js 
    module_b/ 
        some_script.js 
        another_script.js 
vite.config.js
```

### Scenarios

For example, say I'm in this file:

If I import using:
`src/module_a/some_script.js`

```js
import "#/another_script.js"
```

... then, the `#` alias should automatically point to `./src/module_a`

Say when I'm in another module location `./src/module_b/some_script.js`.

The statement:

```js
import '#/another_script.js'
```

... should import `./src/module_b/another_script.js` accordingly.

### Main Question

Is it possible to do this in `vite.config.js`?

`vite.config.js`

```js
    ...
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [vue()],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            '#': (...args) => {
                console.log(args);    // outputs [#, 0, '@/path/of/script/to/import']
                
                // how to get this thing below??? =(
                const filepathOfImportingScript = 
                    getImportingFilepath()  // <--- should return ./src/module_a/some_script.js
                
                const pathOfModule = 
                    getPathOfModule(filepathOfImportingScript);  // returns ./src/module_a/

                return path.resolve(__dirname, pathOfModule);
            }
        }
    })
```

My main problems are...

- How do I create the `getImportingFilepath()` function above which returns the filepath of the script
  that uses the alias `#` to import?
- The function `getPathOfModule()` is easier for me. But, the `getImportingFilepath()` is tricky.

I hope somebody knows, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the answer.
I opened up an issue in vite's repo directly and some awesome guy from Vite answered it. Gonna share the [link](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/10607) here for reference.

Comment: Please expand your answer with further information.

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.